# Asp.net core site hangs after about 50 requests

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I use asp net core 2.0 and faced very strange behavior (at least I see it locally with IIS express). I open site page then press Refresh button about 50 times and site starts hanging, processing of request takes about 40 seconds. Then after about 5 minutes of idle I refresh page again and everything works fast. Next ~50 requests and again it hangs. I'm very confused with that and don't have ideas what is the reason and how to troubleshoot it. I removed all things from code and rest only base code and it's still reproducable.

My Startup class looks so:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    //public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Use(async delegate(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Controller actions don't do anything they just return View. In debugging I often see that it hangs on "await next.Invoke();" line (I've added this delegate only for debugging) but I'm not sure that problem is exactly in action executing.

Maybe anybody knows what can be a reason or how I can troubleshoot it?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe you're hitting some kind of max request for IIS express?

Comment: @Jason Roner, thanks for your response. It's strange but Visual Studio and IIS updating seem to have been solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was solved in unexpected way - I updated Visual Studio and as I saw IIS was also updated together with it.